# How does Bragg assigned $(h,k,l)$ values to planes in his paper?

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals, x-ray-crystallography, braggs-law

I'm reading a Paper by Sir Lawrence Bragg on X-Ray Crystallography. I came across a paragraph which I don't understand after reading many times :

> In the structural diagrams of sodium chloride on the opposite page, the axes of the structure are denoted by the letters $OA, OB$, and $OC$, these being the intervals at which the pattern repeats. In the diagram at the left, the first reflection to appear from the planes perpendicular to $OA$ will be one for which there is a path difference of the two wavelengths between $O$ and $A$, since there are two sheets of atoms in this distance. With respect to the spacing $OA$, then, this initial reflection is a second-order reflection; with respect to the spacings $OB$  and $OC$, however, the same reflection is z zero-order reflection, since the reflecting planes are parallel to both $OB$ and $OC$. Therefore this  type of reflection or diffraction is assigned the order $(200)$, indicating $h=2,k=0$ and $l=0$. Similarly, the initial reflection to appear from the planes in the diagram at the center is $(220)$, whereas for the diagram at the right, it is $(111)$. Higher orders of reflection would, of course, have higher integer values of $h,k$, and $l$.

[image]

I don't understand specifically, *In the diagram at left.....* Can someone help  me how $h,k$ and $l$ values has been assigned to planes?

Please don't tell me some new way (that I know already), I'm interested in what happen here.

Comment: have you found the explanation so far?

Comment: No, I didn't found any explanation